# How do I check the orientation of the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm looking for a quick way to tell if the device is being held with the home button to the right or to the left.  Is there a function to do so?

Answer (score 7):

Look at the `UIDevice` documentation.  There is an orientation property available.  Something like:

```
UIDeviceOrientation d = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

The values of `d` you are looking for are:

`UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft`
- The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.

`UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` 
- The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

Comment: Hmm, that is what I asked for.  What if the device is being laid flat or if it's being held at an improper angle?  It'll return  UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp or UIDeviceOrientationPortrait despite the onscreen display showing landscape.  Hmm, the reason I ask is because my page curl is occuring backwards when the home button is on the left vs right.  I figured I could just reverse them if the orientation is UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft however if it shows another value it won't know what to do.

Comment: Maybe check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160620/how-do-i-detect-the-iphone-orientation-before-rotating - might have some ideas.

Comment: I used your UIDevice and set up a function to only update an integer when it flipped between the two values I was looking for.  Seems to work very well.  Thank you for your help.