# Device orientation will change instead of has changed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uideviceorientation

Is there any way I can perform code before the device orientation animation finishes?

Right now I'm adding myself as an observer to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

However I need my code to finish before the change actually occurs not after.

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation :)

> **Responding to View Rotation Events –**
>
> > > willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
> > >
> > > willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
> > >
> > > didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm not using a UIViewController. That's why I'm trying to us NSNotification Center

Comment: Oh sorry. Then I suggest this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160620/how-do-i-detect-the-iphone-orientation-before-rotating

Comment: Yeah... I basically did that. And used view setNeedsLayout. That way I could change the fields and it would update the display.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change it in this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```